# SQL Server Edition for MS 70-463

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

I just started the MS 70-463 Implementation of warehouse, on the video course the tutor is directing towards SQL Server 2012 Evaluation Edition, but I have already have a SQL Server 2012 Express.

Can someone tell me if that is enough for the course I want to follow please? Is there functionality that I won't be able to perform for the 70-463 course?

Answer (score 8):

No, you will need an Enterprise-equivalent (Evaluation/Developer) Edition to take the 70-463 course. It requires a broad range of Enterprise-only features, including column store indexes and partitioning, among many others.